# Automate dropping a database and creating tables

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-delete

I made a Spotify app that analyzes user data and manages interactive features by writing the API responses to a PostgreSQL database. The developer rules state that basically I have to delete the data when the user is not actively using my app.

Is there a way to automate this on the server (I'm using AWS Lightsail/Ubuntu) to do it daily? Would I need to add a datetime column to all of my tables and follow one of these: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/sql/trigger-delete-old/? Or is there a better way?

Comment: *"basically I have to delete the data when the user is not actively using my app"* – If that is how the spec is worded then you might be able to save yourself some trouble by deleting the *data* (using TRUNCATE TABLE or similar) without deleting the table(s) or the database itself.

Comment: since you are using linux, you can run a cron job to do this, in a simple shell script. I would add a timestamp column in the DB, then using a query in the shell script `DELETE FROM table WHERE date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)` have the cron job run it at 12am everyday.